# почему возвращает не самое минимальное?

Tags: python

```
dict1 = {'ссылка1': '4.50', 'ссылка2': '6.00', 'ссылка3': '19.60', 'ссылка4': '17.40'}

print(min(dict1, key=dict1.get))
```

выводит: **ссылка4**

почему так, если минимальное значение **у ключа 'ссылка1'**
и как это исправить?

Comment: Потому что строки сравниваются посимвольно по алфавиту, а и символ 1 находится по порядку перед символами 4 и 6 и оттого считается самым маленьким

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сортировка в данном случае проходит верно, так как значения в словаре являются *строками*, а не числами и всё сортируется по алфавиту..

Ну а чтобы получить реально минимальное значение, сперва нужно все значения в словаре конвертировать в число:

```py
d = {
    'ссылка1': '4.50',
    'ссылка2': '6.00',
    'ссылка3': '19.60',
    'ссылка4': '17.40'
}

# Конвертируем значения в число
converted_to_num = dict((k, float(v)) for k, v in d.items())

# получаем минимальное значение
print(min(converted_to_num, key=converted_to_num.get))
```